# the difference between WHERE... GROUP BY and GROUP BY....HAVING structure

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, having

I am quite new to SQL, and studying on coursera, here is a project on the final stage of the course. It asks find the distribution of star ratings of restaurants in a given city.
Here is my answer

```
SELECT
stars,
count(stars)
FROM business
group by stars
having city = 'Avon'
```

basically i use the group by..having structure, group by cities first and then filter within the group.However it returned NO results.

The right answer is below

```
SELECT
stars,
count(stars)
FROM business
where city = 'Avon'
group by stars
```

I understand the logic here, filter the city first and then group it by star.

My question is just simple, why my way is incorrect?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` works on the columns result set of the query above it. Your result set from `SELECT stars, COUNT(stars) ... GROUP BY stars` has no `city` column in its result set.

But `WHERE` works on the input table's columns.